# Admin pages on django 1.4 doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I'm trying to establish a simple thing I have done many times before, which is enabling the admin pages on Django, but this time is on 1.4 version.

I keep getting this message over and over (`ImportError at /admin/ No module named django.contrib.auth`).

**This is my urls file:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


from filebrowser.sites import site

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

import django

from django.contrib import auth

from django.contrib.admin import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',  
            url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
            url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)),

            url(r'^polls/', include('volcano.urls')),
            url(r'^contact/', include('form_handle_app.urls')),

            # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
            #url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
            #url(r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')), 
            url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),   
                        )
```

**This is settings file:**

```
 # Django settings for sito project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

import os
#PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = '/home/framoau/sito'

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'testo',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '********',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '********',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/framoau/sito/media/'


# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = 'media' 

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '$hebtpijge6%o*7uegb6!sny5vl0n4w9j2wao-(fxsdb1@kv7b'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
) 

# URL of the login page.
LOGIN_URL = '/contact/login/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                               "django.core.context_processors.debug",
                               "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
                               "django.core.context_processors.media",
                               "django.core.context_processors.static",
                               "django.core.context_processors.tz",
                               "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
                               ) 

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sito.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sito.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    '/home/framoau/sito/templates',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',

    'django.contrib.admindocs',

    'volcano',
    'form_handle_app',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

**My admin page:**

```
from volcano.models import Poll, Choice
from form_handle_app.models import Document


from django.contrib import admin


#admin.site.register(Poll)
#admin.site.register(Choice)
admin.site.register(Document)
```

**Finally, Django's error dump:**

```
> Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.0.4/admin/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'grappelli',
 'filebrowser',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'volcano',
 'form_handle_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  213.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  192.                                            current_app=self.name):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  447.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  290.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  265.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  105.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /admin/
Exception Value: No module named django.contrib.auth
```

I tried importing all the libraries inside manage.py shell console, applied all introspection techniques on all the objects, and everything worked very easily, things only stop when I run Django normally. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :))

The problem is in importing/including other urls in the main url.
Tried to comment this line `url(r'^contact/', include('form_handle_app.urls')),`
 and things went well.

I found out that `uform_handle_app.urls`, has a bad line that doesn't refer to anything (`url(r'^$', 'contact'),`) , and at the same time, django doesn't complain unless it's being touched by the browser; when adding admin pages, all the urls that you have should be fine, even if you will not use them.
`